# Finding representation of integers as 2-adic

Tags: number-theory

How do I find representation of -3, -1/5, and 1/5 as 2-adic integer? Is 2-adic representation same as binary expression: for example, 1/5 = .00110011... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2-adic expansion is totally different from the ordinary binary expansion.  In the ordinary binary expansion, we have $$\frac{1}{5} = .00110011\ldots = 2^{-3} + 2^{-4} + 2^{-7} + 2^{-8} + \ldots$$
but this series does not converge in the 2-adics, because $2^{-n} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ in the 2-adic metric!

To expand negative integers, note that in the 2-adics, we have $$-1 = \ldots 111111 = 1 + 2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4 + \ldots$$

You can also see this by adding 1 to $\ldots 1111$ and noticing that you get 0.  In the 2-adic integers, we can have infinitely many digits to the left of the decimal point, because $2^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ in the 2-adic metric.

ADDED: If you're familiar with how negative numbers are represented in many computers, negation in the 2-adics is taking the [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) of a binary number with infinitely many bits.

In general, to expand a fraction in $2$-adics, you can adapt the standard long division procedure as described here: [How do you take the multiplicative inverse of a p-adic number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250097/how-do-you-take-the-multiplicative-inverse-of-a-p-adic-number)

In the particular case of 1/5, you can also note that $5 = 1 + 2^2$ and use the geometric series $1/(1+x^2) = 1 - x^2 + x^4 - x^6 + \ldots$; substitute $x=2$.  The right side converges in the 2-adics at $x=2$, but you'll have to do some additional manipulation to rewrite the negative terms.  It might be easier to do the long division.

ADDED: Details for the geometric series:

Substituting $x=2$ gives positive terms at positions 0,4,8,..., i.e.,

$\ldots 000100010001 = 1 + 2^4 + 2^8 + ...$

and negative terms at positions 2,6,10,...

$-\ldots 00010001000100 = - 2^2 - 2^6 - 2^{10} - \ldots $

Taking the [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) to get rid of the negative sign,

$\ldots 11101110111100 = - 2^2 - 2^6 - 2^{10} - \ldots $

Now add the first and third lines above to get the final answer (I'll let you finish it; this is just like normal base 2 addition).

```
 ...01000100010001
 ...11101110111100
 -----------------
         ?
```

Comment: Could you explain to me how to solve it with the geometric series you mentioned?

Comment: @PhilipPark some more details added.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!